# Export.image.toDrive keeps failing for certain shapefiles in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am new to GIS. I had been trying to obtain village level images from [kgis](https://kgis.ksrsac.in/kgis/downloads.aspx#Section3). But the GEE code to export images keeps failing with an error message of 'Internal error'. The [code](https://github.com/ishgirwan/gee/blob/master/gee.ipynb)(Jupyter notebook) has worked fine for some district level shapefiles obtained from other website. Part of this code used for exporting:

```
# creating a task to export clipped image to drive
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(clip, 
                                    description = 'image',
                                    folder = 'Landsat',                                    
                                    region = geometry.geometry(),
                                    scale = 30,
                                    crs = 'EPSG:3857'                                    
                                    )
task.start()
```

So, I am not really able to understand how to resolve this issue. Also the number of images obtained even after using filters are really high, which seems weird.

[image]

Comment: Please show the code you are using to export the images in your question.

Comment: I have added the code for export. Also, the link to the whole code is there too if required. Thanks.

Comment: Also: what error message do you get?

Comment: Not getting any error message, the task just fails and no export happens. I have tried with another shapefile which is at district level where the export happens. Another difference is in the size of filtered_collection. For the case where the code has worked, it's only 13 while in the failed case it's almost more than 25k - 80k depending on the village.

Comment: @JonasV I was able to see the error message using  ee.data.getTaskStatus(task.id) and its 'Internal error'